# What if i use Home theater instead of studio monitors for mixing at home?

Tags: speakers, studio

I learned little music mixing at my friend studio. You can say a beginner and i am just about to start my own mixing at home. And, thought to make a setup. But bit confuse about speakers. As my friend use studio monitors in his studio. So, i don't have any clue if i can use home theater. I have low budget i don't know what is better for a home setup.

Comment: Home theatre will be 5 channels at least. Music mix is usually two stereo channels.

Comment: I'd suggest you listen to a very familiar recording through your friend's monitors. Then listen again through your home theatre setup. And see what differences you can hear.

Comment: Do you already have a home theatre setup? Some home theater amplifiers allow you to switch between 5.1 and stereo, where 'stereo' switches off the rear and center channels.

Comment: To start with, just use a decent pair of headphones. You're going to need a pair soon, anyway, so invest in something worth having. If your computer doesn't have separate amp/speakers, on a small budget, look for a pre-loved pair to get you going. Studio monitors are all very well for later - consider what your sounds will be played through by others, which is the sound you'll want them to hear, of course. Most won't be using studio monitors...

Comment: I'd never advocate mixing on headphones if it can be avoided. They're just so easy to be fooled by. Portable mixes, for beginners, do not come from headphone mixes.

Comment: An anecdote: when I started a music hobby I mixed on a normal stereo. I had my mix sounding pretty great on my system, but the first time I played it on another stereo, there was a horrible farting sound after every kick drum - it sounded terrible. Use whatever you have to get started, but be aware that your home cinema system is designed to sound *good*, which most likely means it de-emphasises some frequencies while boosting others.

Answer (score 12):

As a beginner, you can use whatever you can lay your hands on.
As you get more competent, you will start to see the failings in your structure & be more interested & knowledgeable in more specific hardware.

The real down-side of mixing on 'non-standard' equipment is you'll have to carry mixes around from system to system - hi-fi, phone, car - anywhere you can listen to it in a different environment - to see if what you mixed is portable, or only sounds good on one system, the one you mixed it on.

Next issue is that, unless you're mixing for movies, 5.1 is no use to you - if anything, it's a distraction.
You only need stereo [& optionally the sub, if your main L/R speakers are not full-range] so to save distraction you may want to completely disconnect the others.

Most audio/Midi DAWs are designed primarily for stereo, though some are 5.1 capable. Most user listening environments are stereo too, so stay away from 5.1.

Apart from that - go for it, knock yourself out.

*Late edit*
…another one of my 'fun' anecdotes.
I got my first studio setup in 1980 - primitive to say the least. 4-track Teac reel-to-reel & a few synths. The monitoring was an old HH PA amp & one of a pair of PA speakers. Mono. Two-man band, neither of us had ever recorded anything before that. We made about 15 demo tracks on that, and got a record deal out of them [with Pete Waterman, if anyone still remembers that name].
Never say you can't use sh*te equipment & make something half decent out of it. ;)

On the other hand, if someone handed you the best gear & superb monitoring as a total beginner, you still wouldn't yet be able to guarantee results. Your ears & brain need to learn how to match what you think you want with what you're actually getting. Learning to work a studio is as hard as learning to play an instrument, no matter how many 'instant gratification' apps try to make you believe otherwise.

Comment: I got my answer @Tetsujin. I thought to wait and Increase my budget for Monitors. It's better to not waste money on not useful things. I appreciate for helping.